# Parsing JSON Dictionary elements into an NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, json

I am trying to parse a JSON response into an NSArray for a specific item (geometry/location/lat). I easily manage to get the name into an array with

```
for (NSDictionary *object in results)
        {
            NSString *objectName = object[@"name"];
            [MyArray addObject:objectName];
        }
```

but I don't know how to dig down to the "lat" level in order to extract this...

```
JSON DATA full results: (
    {
    geometry =         {
        location =             {
            lat = “15.122494";
            lng = “45.518496";
        };
    };
    icon = "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business.png";
    id = 1767ee03046d7ac7273be472310cfb6d7b2e6;
    name = “Cafe Syracuse”;
    photos =         (
                    {
            height = 768;
            "html_attributions" =                 (
                "From a Google User"
            );
            "photo_reference" = "CnRoAAAAlVZmfP0Dn3HIwcaEozcjYHqPMC_VlWcvz2sH0yYNjv9DS1GIccAvAp-LNaWxAWKvnEifhPU-1b8ETx7sXtOR7UKSs7tOBpai4FPM1y6M-lcL2qJ4M0dizbHStidxuGCF_QnE548qsE1tP2ZTdhjY_BIQKxSTS_-rPxGlOZmAG7oUUBSiV276H4CemarEXRozEtVr5Vs";
            width = 1024;
        }
    );
    "place_id" = ChIJB6K6CExRr8f4AvaA09U;
    rating = "4.5";
    reference = "CnRjAAAA5Yh4QrEnn7xH2URR7-gwwrhbUz2qmlwbCRW4-JkMfINdldXIYhQR8p2kTdiZiYsdX67nwINp963XIxysFPWOAVZ-okFCu0VH9NL66EWiPSVBFGSgYKXCd7LuhOFMgeU1yLuegyCMQ7RX6mjkhIQiVVok262SeOJGsChxoUXx6DKhp7t_uM51w2y9_bJAlscAA";
    scope = GOOGLE;
    types =         (
        cafe,
        establishment
    );
    vicinity = “White glacier";
},
    {
    geometry =  //Other item
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would help you to get lat and long:

```
NSString*lat=  [[[object valueForKey:@"geometry"] valueForKey:@"location"] valueForKey:@"lat"];
NSString *lng= [[[object valueForKey:@"geometry"] valueForKey:@"location"] valueForKey:@"lng"];
```